# How do I change the drag threshold in a windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with users dragging objects when selecting them.  I have tried several methods using the mouse events to set a less sensitive threshold. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142577/mouse-cursor-position-changes).

They are not working primarily I think because I am using the Piccolo graphics engine.

I know this can be done via the registry but I don't want to mess with my users registry entries.

The alternative seems to be to use pinvoke with `SystemParametersInfo;` and the SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT and SPI_SETDRAGWIDTH parameters.

I know how to invoke it,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);
```

And I know the `uiAction` parameters values are,

`SPI_SETDRAGHEIGHT = 0x004D`

`SPI_SETDRAGWIDTH = 0x004C`

I know `uiParam` is the width or height.

Beyond that I am stuck.  I really don't understand this stuff and have no idea as to how to set the last two parameters.

There is C++(?) code [here](http://www.parkscomputing.com/2009/04/windows-drag-sensitivity-utility/).

But my knowledge of C variants and converting them to C# is lamentable.

So could someone please help me to set the drag drag threshold within my application?

Comment: I suspect that Piccolo implements its own drag & drop functionality and that if you want to rely on their library then you're stuck with whatever threshold Piccolo uses.  Piccolo may not (and probably doesn't) allow the threshold to be modified via registry settings.  You could ask other Piccolo users if the setting is configurable.

Comment: @RogerN  you are correct and the drag handler seemed to ignore all my efforts and affecting it.  It's really why I'd like to go the pinvoke route

Comment: Pass IntPtr.Zero, the argument is not used for this setting.  And 2 for the last argument, it lets every running program know that you changed the system setting.  And yes, the user will hate you, make sure your uninstaller is reliable.  There isn't much point in using open source software if you don't want to change the source :)

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I hope to read the value and then reset it before the app closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected the Piccolo source code and found that the drag threshold does *not* depend on your system settings, so using PInvoke to call SystemParametersInfo won't help you here.  However, the threshold is configurable by changing the `MinDragStartDistance` property of the `PDragSequenceEventHandler` object.  The default value is 0, which probably explains why your users are frustrated with it being too sensitive.

I have no experience using Piccolo, though, so I can't really comment on how to gain access to that particular property.

Comment: Thank you.  I have found that property and it works.